# With IIS7, how can you enforce FTPS for some ftp user and not for others?

Tags: iis-7, ftps

We have configured ftp within IIS7 to allow the use of SSL certificates. We need to ensure that most of your users use FTPS, but due to legacy system we cannot enforce all ftp users to use SSL. What would we need to do to achieve this?

Comment: SFTP is SSH File Transfer Protocol which has nothing to do with FTP and is not supported by IIS. Please re-phrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

he didn't say SFTP, he said FTPS which is FTP over SSL... FTP over SSL is indeed FTP (not ssh) run over an SSL'd connection, and is supported by IIS 7.x.  Like the user, I too have not been able to find a mechanism for enforcing FTPS and disallowing clear text auth... IIS 7.x's FTP server seems to only make FTPS available as an option, but does not provide a mechanism (that I can find yet) for enforcing/requiring it.